# killall doesn't work if I call it from a script

Tags: bash, scripting, kill, tcpdump

I'm starting a tcpdump inside a script and I also kill it from the same script. So I'm currently using the `killall` command for this:
The script gets executed from an udev rule:
This is the section, which should terminate the tcpdump:
In addition I also use `-s SIGKILL`, because I've read that this could also help.

What is the problem that killall doesn't terminate the tcpdump. When I start the script manually it is all working properly.

```
 if [[ "$pid1" != "" ]];then
          sudo killall -s SIGKILL tcpdump
          sh /tmp/scripts/autoumount.sh &
          sudo kill -9 $$
          echo "autodump stopped"
```

Comment: Since you start the process, you can save the pid and kill it specifically - why use killall?

Comment: Have you tried using the full path for `killall`?  It's possible that since this is being invoked by udev that it's running with a limited environment.

Comment: Are you quite sure that it's not `sudo` asking for your password?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz When I start it from the udev rule, I don't get any output so I can't really debug it. But it could be, because the script is located on a usb stick

Comment: @DavidKing No I didn't tried that, but It should work, because it also worked when I started manually from the exact same place.

Comment: sudo should not be in a udev rule?

Comment: @apuboard Except that when you start it manually it's running with your env instead of the limited one that udev is running it with.  Put in the full path and I'll bet it works.

Comment: Who said `SIGKILL` was appropriate? It's totally overkill, and may leave the system in a worse state (e.g. shared memory left open, child processes not cleaned up, and so forth).